# Prestashop TCPDF pdf invoice

Tags: prestashop, tcpdf, invoice

I can`t solve this prestashop invoice problem. Prestashop use TCPDF to generate PDF invoice.

This is my footer.tpl code:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%">
            <img src="http://myshop.com/img/invoicefooter.jpg"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As u can see, I include image on footer. And Prestashop generate header and footer on every page. So its okey for me, but let you show:
This is example of invoice with 2 pages: first page footer ( http://prntscr.com/6nn5c9 ) and this is the last page footer - http://prntscr.com/6nn5lo

I can`t understand what`s wrong. I tried to look at TCPDF.php functions footer, getfooter() and etc..

Briefly, if I have 1 page PDF invoice it shows correct. If I have PDF invoice with 2 pages I got correct view only on last page...

Thanks for any help! Its very important for me..

Comment: Best way to add a background image is via TCPDF -> setImage, not via template. I can't look it up now, but this is the genral idea.

Comment: Any error from TCPDF? Prestashop version?
I suppose latest version and "Unable to get image error" yes?

Comment: How to check it? Does dev mode works at pdf? Version: 1.6.0.9.

Answer (score 2):

Mh, I found a solution. I really dont know why and don`t have too much time to look for bug, but this method help me to add correct image on every page footer.

Extend PDFGenerator.php in prestashop/classes/pdf and look for function footer:

```
$this->Image($image_file, 11, 241, 189, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

Use function Image to put image on footer. Now I can see correct image on every page.